# Stretch the table of balances, for all dates of the calendar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I have a table of stock balances, as of the date of their change
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f96fc/2)

I need to stretch these Remains to missing dates including 0 leftovers

I created a calendar

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar
("Date" DATE)
GO

DECLARE @start datetime
DECLARE @end datetime

SET @start = (SELECT MIN (a.Date) FROM Remains a)
SET @end = GETDATE();

WITH cte AS
(
SELECT @start "Date"
UNION all
SELECT "Date" + 1
FROM cte
WHERE "Date" < @end
)
INSERT INTO Calendar
SELECT cast("Date" AS date) AS "Date"
FROM cte
WHERE "Date" < GETDATE()

option(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Where I take the minimum date from the Remains table and drag it until today
[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIplV.png)

Next, I join the Calendar to the table of Remains using OUTER APPLY,

```
SELECT 
      b.Date
     ,x.W_Code 
     ,x.Prod_Code
     ,x.Quality
     ,x.Count
FROM Calendar b
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT
      a.Date
     ,a.W_Code
     ,a.Prod_Code
     ,a.Quality
     ,a.Count 
FROM Remains a
WHERE a.Date = b.Date AND a.Prod_Code = N'00005026957' AND a.W_Code = N'000000017' ) x
```

and if my query applies to 1 specific warehouse, product and quality, then I get the desired result

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beWUA.png)

But if I remove the condition for the warehouse and the product, the table built incorrectly

I need for each group W_Code, Prod_Code, Quality
have each date from the Calendar

Please help me to find a way to implement this
Maybe I don't need a Calendar
I read about recursive CTE but did not understand how to apply it

How to fill the table with values further, I know, the problem is in the correct joining of the table with dates

Thanks

Comment: You need to `CROSS JOIN` your dates to the `DISTINCT` values of the columns you want a row for each date of. Also, I suggest a set-based method for creating your calendar table.  Depending how long ago your value for `MIN (a.Date)` date, the recursive option will be pretty slow comparatively.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the truth

80.000 - Good's
50 - Warehouses
date interval 2013-12-31 - Today

Think i need create OLAP Cube and i am try, but I have only just begun to understand SQL
When creating a cube, I encountered errors that could not be quickly solved and  I returned to the solution on the SQL

Comment: It looks like the truth? What truth? Huh?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/yO9bctK.png 
I am try what u advice
Than i need Outer apply Result to Remains table i think